# Cannot get proper div with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I have this codepen with a basic jquery plugin.

https://codepen.io/stephendesjardins/pen/jZZozK

When I click on the div box. I want it to find his .dot div and add class "haya".

For some odd reason it add it to the second box instead of the first one.

They wanted me to add more details to post this post. So I guess, I can say that I found the plugin template on github.

```
 /*!
 * jQuery lightweight plugin boilerplate
 * Original author: @ajpiano
 * Further changes, comments: @addyosmani
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */

// the semi-colon before the function invocation is a safety
// net against concatenated scripts and/or other plugins
// that are not closed properly.
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    // undefined is used here as the undefined global
    // variable in ECMAScript 3 and is mutable (i.e. it can
    // be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really
    // being passed in so we can ensure that its value is
    // truly undefined. In ES5, undefined can no longer be
    // modified.

    // window and document are passed through as local
    // variables rather than as globals, because this (slightly)
    // quickens the resolution process and can be more
    // efficiently minified (especially when both are
    // regularly referenced in your plugin).

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = "defaultPluginName",
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
      console.log(element);
        that = this;
        this.element = element;

        // jQuery has an extend method that merges the
        // contents of two or more objects, storing the
        // result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty because we don't want to alter
        // the default options for future instances of the plugin
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function() {
            // Place initialization logic here
            // You already have access to the DOM element and
            // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element
            // and this.options
            // you can add more functions like the one below and
            // call them like so: this.yourOtherFunction(this.element, this.options).

          $(this.element).on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('bleh');
            $(that.element).find('.dot').addClass('haya')
          })
        },

        yourOtherFunction: function(el, options) {
            // some logic
        }
    };

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

  })( jQuery, window, document );

  $('.box').defaultPluginName();

  $('.box2').defaultPluginName();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(that.element)` is targeting the second parent div. Change `$(that.element).find('.dot').addClass('haya')` to `$(this).find('.dot').addClass('haya')`

Comment: This makes sens. The plugin goes twice into everything with the init. so if you get a clickevent after the fact, it will remember the last item only.